# Animator.SetTrigger does not trigger an Animation

Tags: unity, c#, animation

I have a basic animator setup for my Unity Character which has a "block" functionality when pressing the E key. So far, so good.

However I've made a transition from "Blocking Idle" to "Blocking_React" (which means that the character was hit) using a Trigger "tookDamage" (default to false).
The problem is that the character gets hit but does not transition to "Blocking_React" animation.

Code Sample:

```
//From Character Controller script
if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E) && !_isBlocking)
        {
            _animator.SetBool("isBlocking", true);
            _isBlocking = true;
        }
        else if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.E) && _isBlocking)
        {
            _animator.SetBool("isBlocking", false);
            _isBlocking = false;
        }
//------------------------
//From my Character script

public void TakeDamage(float damage)
    {
        health -= damage;
        this.GetComponent<Animator>().SetTrigger("tookDamage");
    }
```

And this is my transition:

[image: animator screenshot]

Am I missing something?

Comment: Have you checked that TakeDamage method is called on hit? How you exit from the React state? Is the Idle state the active one upon hit?

Comment: The TakeDamage method is called each time the player gets hit, yes! I simply linked the transition back to Blocking Idle with "has Exit Time" checked, nothing special! @Nikaas

Comment: The only reason I see for this not to work is that you are not in the Standing_Block_Idle state when SetTrigger is called.

Comment: That's what is weird, while holding down "E" it enters the Standing_Block_idle state successfully, it just doesn't transition to Standing_Block_React_Large... @UriPopov Could it be a bug?

Comment: I dont know I tried replicating it and it worked fine for me. You could try changing the blend on the transition maybe that is messing it up.

Comment: So I deleted and re-imported my animations and set up the animator from scratch and it works... Very weird... @UriPopov Anyway thanks for your time people. I still wonder what the issue was :/